# Sqlalichemy : Loading related objects ids in parent property

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

With the following tables and mappings

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = None
        self.b_ids = {}
        self.b_s = {}

class B:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.id = None
        self.a_id = None
        self.a = None

a = Table('t_a', meta,
    Column('id',Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True),
    )

b = Table('t_b', meta,
    Column('id',Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True),
    Column('a_id', Integer, ForeignKey('t_a.id')),
    )

mapper(A, a)
mapper(B, b, properties={'a' : relationship(A, backref="b_s")})
```

When I load 'A' I can get the related 'B' objects in the 'b_s' property. But What I want is a list of ids of related Bs in the A.b_ids property. Is there a way to do this?

I tried :

```
mapper(A, a, properties={'b_ids' : 
                         column_property(select(
                                                [b.c.id], 
                                                a.c.id==b.c.a_id))
                         })
```

But its giving error: 'ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

column_property() is used to add another column to the SELECT statement, such as this:

```
SELECT a.x, a.y, (SELECT b.id FROM b where a.id=b.a_id) AS b_id FROM a
```

In SQL, that's a subquery in the columns clause of the SELECT statement, and it needs to return exactly one row/column for each row - in SQLAlchemy we call this a "scalar select".

In this case you're looking for a list, so that's not embedded into the main columns clause there.   That's why the database returns an error for that.  Your mapping already has a list of "b ids" on it, in the form of "b_s".  You just want to extract the "id" from that, and this can be done pretty easily with the association proxy:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class A(object):
    # ... other things
    b_ids = association_proxy('b_s', 'id')
```

When you access "a.b_ids", it will look at each entry within "b_s" and extract the "id" attribute, returning a collection that's compatible with the type of collection of "b_s", which in this case is a Python list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have added some of my doubts as an answer as its was not fitting into the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting association_proxy in the mapper properties. But it was not allowing. Also the alchemy documentation says "The proxy is a Python property, and unlike the mapper relationship, is defined in your class". So I assume we can't keep the mapping for this inside mapper().

Anyways, I can't modify the model class as its generated code. So I tried the below:

```
a = Table('t_a', meta,
    Column('id',Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True),
    )

b = Table('t_b', meta,
    Column('id',Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True),
    Column('a_id', Integer, ForeignKey('t_a.id')),
    )

mapper(A, a)
mapper(B, b, properties={'a' : relationship(A, backref="b_s")})

A.b_ids=association_proxy('b_s', 'id')
```

This seems to be working. So is it be ok to do this way? Or is there a better way?

Regards,
Litty

Comment: if you are given a class already, then sticking on the attribute after the fact is how to do it, yup.